# System.IO.Exception error: "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."

Tags: c#, xml, ioexception

I received a very weird IOException when writing to an XML file:

```
System.IO.IOException: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter..ctor(String filename, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)
```

The error happened when I called XmlDocument's Save(string) function.

Any ideas on what happened?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Looks like another process had the file open using the file mapping (shared memory) APIs.

The find function in Process Explorer should be able to tell you.

Comment: It could also be transient (just happened to me, next write attempt was fine but I failed on the next file, which then worked fine on next attempt), like when an antivirus scanner is rocking through your world.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like the file you're trying to write is already open elsewhere, either by your code or by another process.

Do you have the file open in an editor?  Do you have some other code that reads it, but forgets to close it?

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out which process has open file handle on it - use the `Find` / `Find handle or DLL...` command.

Comment: No Find / Find handle or DLL in Win 2012 r2 :/

Answer (score 7):

Try excluding the file from your project while you debug. I found that it was in fact VS2010 which was holding the XML file.
You can then select "Show all files" in your solution explorer to check the XML file post debug.

A lock will stop the issue when doing multiple writes.

```
lock(file){ write to file code here }
```

Answer (score 5):

The OS or Framework can fail you, if you try to open the same file over and over again in a tight loop, for example

```
 while (true) {
   File.WriteAllLines(...)
 }
```

Of course, you don't want to actually do that. But a bug in your code might cause that to happen. The crash is not due to your code, but a problem with Windows or the .NET Framework.

If you have to write lots of files very quickly, you could add a small delay with Thread.Sleep() which also seems to get the OS off your back.

```
 while (i++<100000000) {
   File.WriteAllLines(...)
   Thread.Sleep(1);
 }
```

Comment: putting "A small sleep which fixes it for some reason" is never a good idea :(

Comment: I clarified my response. I realize that small sleeps are not a good idea, but sometimes that is all you can do at the mercy of the OS or the framework.  This crashed happened with .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the records in xml document were being iterated and in each iteration the records were being edited and saved. I changed this logic to save the file once after all the records are edited and poofff.. the error is gone.