# File access synchronized on Java object

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an object responsible for persisting `JTable` state to disk. It saves/loads visible columns, their size, position etc. A few interesting bits from its class definition are below.

```
class TableSaver {
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);

    TableSaver() {
        timer.schedule(new TableSaverTimerTask(), 15000, SAVE_STATE_PERIOD);
    }

    synchronized TableColumns load(PersistentTable table) {
        String xml = loadFile(table.getTableKey());
        // parse XML, return
    }

    synchronized void save(String key, TableColumns value) {
        try {
            // Some preparations
            writeFile(app.getTableConfigFileName(key), xml);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ... handle
        }
    }

    private class TableSaverTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (TableSaver.this) {
                Iterator<PersistentTable> iterator = queue.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    PersistentTable table = iterator.next();
                    if (table.getTableKey() != null) {
                        save(table.getTableKey(), dumpState(table));
                    }
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- There only exists one instance of `TableSaver`, ever.
- `load()` can be called from many threads. Timer clearly is another thread.
- `loadFile()` and `writeFile()` do not leave open file streams - they use a robust, well tested and broadly used library which always closes the streams with `try ... finally`.

Sometimes this fails with an exception like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\path\to\table-MyTable.xml (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
    at package.FileUtil.writeFile(FileUtil.java:33)
    at package.TableSaver.save(TableSaver.java:175)
    at package.TableSaver.access$600(TableSaver.java:34)
    at package.TableSaver$TableSaverTimerTask.run(TableSaver.java:246)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\path\to\table-MyTable.xml (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at package.FileUtilWorker.writeFile(FileUtilWorker.java:57)
    ... 6 more
```

So I have two questions:

1. How can this kind of synchronization fail? Note that I am sure there only is one instance of `TableSaver`.
2. What is this thing in the stacktrace: `package.TableSaver.access$600(TableSaver.java:34)`? Line 34 is the line with `class TableSaver {`. Can this be the reason why the synchronization is not working?

Comment: can you post your `writeFile()` code?

Comment: Regarding #2, no that's not a problem.  That is just a compiler artefact of calling a private member of the enclosing class from a nested inner class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=FileNotFoundException+%22The+requested+operation+cannot+be+performed+on+a+file+with+a+user-mapped+section+open%22) learns me that this seems to be Windows specific. Here's an extract of [Bug 6354433](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6354433):

> This is Windows platform issue with memory-mapped file, i.e. `MappedByteBuffer`. The Java 5.0 doc for `FileChannel` state that "the buffer and the mapping that it represents will remain valid until the buffer itself is garbage-collected". The error occurs when we tried to re-open the filestore and the mapped byte buffer has not been GC. Since there is no `unmap()` method for mapped byte buffer (see bug 4724038), we're at the mercy of the underlying operating system on when the buffer get free up. Calling `System.gc()` might free up the buffer but it is not guarantee. The problem doesn't occurs on Solaris; may be due to the way shared memory is implemented on Solaris. So the work-around for Windows is not to use memory-mapped file for the transaction information tables.

What Java/Windows version are you using? Does it have the latest updates?

Here are two other related bugs with some useful insights:

- [Bug 4715154](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4715154) - Memory mapped file cannot be deleted.
- [Bug 4469299](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4469299) - Memory mapped files are not GC'ed.

---

As to your second question, that's just the autogenerated classname of an inner or anonymous class.

Comment: What if I am using `java.io.FileOutputStream` and `java.io.FileInputStream` and not NIO?

Comment: It is using NIO under the hoods.

Comment: so what should we use then? can you tell me im having same problem on desktop windows 7 while with laptop it was fine, in linux there is no problem. I used printwriter, bufferedwriter and nio, all had same problem

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no issues with the code I have seen this occur when a virus scanner is running in the background which is cheerfully opening files to scan them behind the scenes.  If you have a memory resident virus scanner that checks files in the background try disabling it, or at least disabling it for the directory you reading from/writing to.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Are you sure it's not related to file permission? Does the application has write privilege to this folder? To this file?

---

[EDIT] This seems to be Windows related, not Java [The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302698/system-io-exception-error-the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with some tightly threaded Java code.  I took a look at the referenced .NET conversation and the penny dropped.  It is simply that I have contention for the same file, among different threads.  Looking more closely the contention is (*also*) for some internals too.  So my best course is to **synchronize-d** around the shared object when the update it.

This works and the error dissolves in the mist.

```
    private static   ShortLog   tasksLog     = new ShortLog( "filename" );
    private static   Boolean    tasksLogLock = false;

      ...

    synchronized( tasksLogLock ){
        tasksLog.saveLastDatum( this.toString() );
    }
```

*see also*:

- [Synchronization of non-final field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field)

Answer (score 0):

Your synchronization only protects against access from your own process. If you want to protect against accesses from any process, you have to use file locking:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html