# synchronization on an arrayList java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synchronization of non-final field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field)

I have an arrayList and when i use this:

```
//declare it as a global ArrayList
private ArrayList <Human> myList = new ArrayList <Human>() ;

//inside a method
synchronized (myList){     
    for(  ListIterator<Human> it = myList.listIterator();it.hasNext();){  
       Human = it.next();
```

it tells me Synchronization on non-final field. what should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field

Comment: i search on the internet not in stackoverflow. i'm sorry guys.how can i delete this?

Comment: At the bottom of the question, under the tags, there should be a `delete` link.

Comment: There are delete and close buttons under the Tags of your question, use it

Answer (score 2):

You can synchronize on non-final field (myList on this example)

You can use synchronized block without parameter

```
synchronized{     
    for(  ListIterator<Human> it = myList.listIterator();it.hasNext();){  
       Human = it.next();
```

Or create another class property with "final" attribute.

PS. You can use foreach loop as well

```
for(Human h : myList){  
           h.getName();
}
```