# Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronization

I have two thread and a ArrayList in my program. I want to access list from my threads.

```
public void run() {
...
arraylist.add(myObj);
...
}

public void run() {
...
arraylist.remove(myObj);
...
}
```

I tried Synchronization each of thread.

```
 synchronized (arraylist) 
 {  
    //add or remove
 }
```

but it said "Synchronization of non-final field".

Comment: ....so make it final? anyway i think syn on ono-file is a warning, not an error

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` generally means you are modifying the collection **while you are iterating over it**. Generally nothing to do with threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Synchronization of non-final field** [is only a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field)  that you can safely ignore.
If the `arraylist` is only assigned in the constructor, you can declare it as `final` and get rid of the warning.

You need to synchronize on the list, because the `remove` method is not inherently thread-safe (one thread may modify the list **while** `remove` is searching for the element to be removed).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are other operation on `arraylist` without synchronization.

`Synchronization of non-final field` this warning gives by compiler when there are number of threads to synchronize a block of code correctly they need to synchronize on the same object instance.