# The right way to synchronize on non-final object in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm trying to protect an object with a lock.

I didn't choose mutexes because of ugly syntax of "try..catch".

Browsing stackoverflow, I came to a conclusion that this is how to properly achieve my goal:

```
class MyClass {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private Channel channel = null;

    public void setChannel() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            channel = new Channel();
            synchronized (channel) {
                // setup channel
            }
        }
    }

    public void unsetChannel() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            synchronized (channel) {
                channel.close();
            }
        channel = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean isSet() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (channel == null)
                return false;
            synchronized (channel) {
                return channel.isActive();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems ugly and hard to read...

How can I improve readability of my solution?

Comment: why lock on a newly created object?  Could also synchronise the whole method

Comment: @ScaryWombat I want to do setup on created object before any usage. Shouldn't I do this? I don't want to synchronize whole methods because I cleaned code of my methods for simplisity's sake

Comment: You could improve the readability by making it legal Java, for starters.  Are your methods part of a class?  Are they supposed to be part of `MyClass`?  What's `m_channelLock`?  Regardless, I don't see anything uglier than normal about your code, where synchronization is concerned.  Since I don't know what `m_channelLock` is, I can't tell whether you can simplify things any.

Comment: In `setChannel` as it is already locked, there is no point in `locking` again.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't think that's necessarily true.  Other code could synchronize on `channel` without synchronizing on `lock` first, so the nested `synchronize` may be necessary.  Unfortunately, since there are errors in the posted code, I can't tell for sure whether it makes a difference.

Comment: @ajb Yes, you are right if we are not assuming that `m_channelLock` is a typo and he means `lock`

Comment: @ajb it was a typo, sorry. I came from a c++ background and there we have LockGuards oneliners, so I'm not used to those java staircases in simplemethods like `isSet()` here (6 lines, really?) :)

Comment: If `isSet()` really synchronizes on `lock`, then Scary Wombat is right and there's no reason to synchronize on `channel`, because the lock on `lock` will already prevent any other code from getting to the point where it tries to access `channel`.

Comment: @ajb the guy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field/21462631#21462631) said you should syncronize on protected object "for the sake of RAM synchronisation", who is right then?

Comment: I think you could get the same effect by declaring `channel` to be `volatile`, instead of synchronizing on it.  The person at your link seemed to say that you have to declare _all_ instance fields to be volatile, but I don't think that's correct--only the ones that need to be.  If you have a case where multiple threads may be accessing the same field (and some could be writes), then it should be `volatile`.

Comment: @ajb, thanks, I appreciate your comments, `volatile` it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your locking strategy:

```
class MyClass {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private Channel channel = null;

    public void setChannel() {
        // other code can go here

        synchronized (lock) {
            channel = new Channel();
            // setup channel
        }

        // other code can go here
    }

    public void unsetChannel() {

        // other code can go here

        synchronized (lock) {
            channel.close();
            channel = null;
        }

        // other code can go here
    }

    public boolean isSet() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (channel == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return channel.isActive();
        }
    }
}
```

In effect, the `lock` object protects any access to the channel variable.

**Edited** to show where other code that does not interact with `channel` might live outside of the locks.

Comment: the guy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21462631/4440694) said you should syncronize on protected object "for the sake of RAM synchronisation". So whom should I believe? :)

Comment: That only applies if your lock object is non-final. In my example, I am locking the final object `lock`.

Comment: i want to protect non-final "channel" object, so is your solution eligible?

Comment: If you wrap every access to the `channel` object with the lock as I have above, the solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

The outer lock on `lock` protects everything. You don't need the second lock. A second thread can never reach it while the outer lock is held.

Comment: the guy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field/21462631#21462631) said you should syncronize on protected object "for the sake of RAM synchronisation". Is one lock is really enough?