# Synchronized() block is not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

```java
private static Integer balance=0;

public static void deposit(final int amt) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized(balance) {
                System.out.println("Balance at start is: "+balance);        
                balance+=amt;
                System.out.println("deposited " + Integer.toString(amt) + " to funds. Now at " + Integer.toString(balance));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I run the above simple deposit function, I expect that two threads should not enter at same time in synchronized block. But with operation Sequence as below:

1. Depo100
2. Depo200
3. Depo700

Output is as below:

```
------------------
Balance at start is: 0
deposited 100 to funds. Now at 100
Balance at start is: 100
Balance at start is: 100
deposited 700 to funds. Now at 800
deposited 200 to funds. Now at 1000
```

As we can see two threads entered at same time in the synchronized block and accessed balance object which is NOT expected.
        What I am doing wrong here ? I am newbie for Multithreading. 
        Thanks in advance.

Comment: `balance` is a different object each time. There's no mutual exclusion.

Comment: Note that you don't need to call `Integer.toString(amt)` when you are building a string using `+`: string concatenation automatically does that for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Integer` (like all primitive wrapper classes) is *immutable*. Every time you "add a number to it", you're actually setting the field to a new instance:

```
balance += amt;
```

is actually evaluated as follows:

```
balance = Integer.valueOf(balance.intValue() + amt);
```

So you're synchronizing on different objects each time (unless `amt` happens to be zero, and `balance.intValue()` is [in the range cached by your JVM's implementation of `Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int))).

You need a *fixed* value that you can synchronize on. You can use a fixed reference with a *mutable* value, for example an `Integer[]` with length 1, or an `AtomicInteger` (although synchronizing on an `AtomicInteger` always feels a bit wrong to me - but actually, you don't need to use synchronization because you can use `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement` or `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet`).

---

Note that you should probably make the reference to the thing you synchronize on `final`, to avoid accidentally setting it to some different value and breaking the mutual exclusion again.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to get my head around AtomicInteger. Could you explain more on your Note part plz.

Comment: Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) pointed, it is because synchronization is done on an immutable instance which is being modified inside `synchronized` block.

**Solution 1:** As suggested by Andy, to use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

**Solution 2:** To use synchronization on a dummy object like this:

```
private static Object dummy = new Object();

private static Integer balance = 0;

public static void deposit(final int amt) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (dummy) {
                // System.out.println(balance.hashCode());
                System.out.println("Balance at start is: " + balance);
                balance += amt;
                System.out.println(
                        "deposited " + Integer.toString(amt) + " to funds. Now at " + Integer.toString(balance));
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```