# Possibility of deadlock with two locks?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

Can this code deadlock with thread 1 calling `one` and thread 2 calling `two`. That is, can the acquisition of the inner lock be reordered to before the acquisition of the outer one (from the POV of the other thread)?

```java
private final Object foo = new Object();
synchronized  void one() {
    // ...
    synchronized(this.foo) {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
}

synchronized void two() {
    // ...
    synchronized(this.foo) {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @AndyTurner One intrinsic lock on `this`, one intrinsic lock on `this.foo`

Comment: @michalk I also don't think so -- I think the acquire semantics on the `this` lock prevents operations from being reordered to before it, but I can't reason with the terms in the spec.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Intrinsic/monitor lock.

Comment: The original code uses actual `java.util.concurrent.lock.Lock`s, but I think this example is equivalent.

Comment: The problem might be that between calls to those functions `this.foo` might point to different object - then you have a problem.

Comment: @michalk Indeed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910807/synchronization-of-non-final-field

Comment: Ok let's assume `foo` is final.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the functions are obviously not identical. They will do different things before, during and after the inner `synchronized` block.

Comment: Sorry!, my eyes skipped over the `foo = new Object()` assignment. My previous comments are invalid because of that.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not deadlock.

When synchronized methods are called the intrinsic lock of `this` is locked before the method’s body is executed. Here either thread 1 or thread 2 will get to run its method, and the other one will not be able to lock on the intrinsic lock of `this.foo` so the owner of the lock of `this` will be able to lock `this.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

So for with a Simple Test :

```
class LockTest implements Runnable {
    public final Object foo = new Object();
    boolean runOne;

    public LockTest(boolean runOne) {
        this.runOne = runOne;
    }

    synchronized void  one() {
        System.out.println("runnin one function");
        synchronized(this.foo) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter Sleep function one");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized void  two() {
        System.out.println("running two function");
        synchronized(this.foo) {
            try {
                System.out.println("enter sleep function two");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(runOne)
        one();
        else
            two();
    }
}
```

With this in a Main class :

```
while (true)
        {
            LockTest document2 = new LockTest(true);
            LockTest document3 = new LockTest(false);
            Thread tread1 = new Thread(document2);
            Thread tread2 = new Thread(document3);
            tread1.start();
            tread2.start();
            a++;
            if(a==10)
                break;

        }
```

We are not locking and even watching with a Thread Dump everything is working Fine. Why? Because every time we are initializating a new Thread with a new object foo. But if that object is declared as static it will be a lock and the others threads need to wait. So from my test and POV. No, it can't be deadlocked.